Regarding react-query, while using refetch my data and error variables are not invalidated between renders
When clicking on button to get data, previous data/error is not getting cleared.
New data is getting appended. I've tried various options in react-query but none solved my issue.
Version used > @tanstack/react-query: "5.52.2"
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import React from "react";
import { mockAPICall } from "./helper/mockAPICall";

const FetchQuery = () => {
  const { data, error, refetch, isFetching } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["repoData"],
    queryFn: mockAPICall,
    enabled: false,
    retry: false,
  });

  const clicked = () => {
    refetch();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="flex m-auto border-solid border-black px-7 py-3 border-2 hover:border-gray-400 active:text-gray-400"
        onClick={clicked}
      >
        React Query
      </button>
      <div className="py-3 flex m-auto justify-center">
        {isFetching && (
          <div className="text-slate-400">{"Loading..."}</div>
        )}
        {data && <div className="text-green-500">{data}</div>}
        {error && <div className="text-red-500">{error}</div>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FetchQuery;

and mockAPI code as below
export const mockAPICall = () => {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 0));
  console.log(" > mockAPICall > randomNum:", randomNum);

  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (randomNum < 50) {
        res("Successful Response "+ randomNum);
        console.log("success");
      } else {
        rej("Intended Err "+ randomNum);
        console.log("fail");
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
};

I'm uploading GIF below to show you what I'm facing


Solved by using queryClient.resetQueries(['repoData']) before refetch()
